# Limit number of numbers in input text jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a calculator using JQuery and want to **limit the input box to only 8 digits.**
My calculator only allows user to input value with buttons not keys.

HTML

```
<input class = "result" type-"text"  maxlength="8" disabled />
```

This alone doesn't work as I'm using JQuery.

JQuery

```
// Click number
$(".b").click(function() {
    var currentVal = $result.val();
    var number = $(this).attr("value");
    var newVal = number;
    if(currentVal === "0") {
        newVal = number;
    } else {
        if (clear == true) {
            $result.val(newVal);
            clear = false;
        } else {
            newVal = currentVal + number;
        }
    }
    $result.val(newVal);
});
```

Comment: Show the code that adds new digits to the textbox.  That's where your maximum-value logic needs to be implemented.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've added the JQuery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
$result.val(newVal);
```

to

```
if (newVal.length <= 8) $result.val(newVal);
```

Comment: @JOG: Please elaborate on "didn't work".  e.g., you pressed 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 the textbox contains "12345678", and then pressing 9 makes it show what exactly?

Comment: @JOG: You did change the one at the end of the function, right?  Because there's another one inside the `if (clear)` branch that doesn't matter.